# Connecting to a GPS Deamon service in c#

Tags: c#, gps, gpsd

I am working on an application where I need to get my location through a **GPSD service**. I am using **C#** for my library (same as the project), which is not supported by GPSD itself, so they don't have any library. That's why I am trying to create my own library (and eventually make a nuget package of it).

But I got stuck with the following problem. I get a connection with the GPSD service through sockets, and I get the following data:

```
{"class":"VERSION","release":"3.11","rev":"3.11-3","proto_major":3,"proto_minor":9}
```

So the connection is working, but I don't know how to get the GPS data itself, there is not much documentation about it so, **does anybody have any experience with this, or know how I can achieve this?**

```
using (var client = ConnectViaHttpProxy(ServerAddress, Port, ProxyAddress, Port))
{
    while (client.Connected)
    {
        var result = new byte[256];
        client.Client.Receive(result);


        //_response = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
        _response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(result, 0, result.Length);
        var resultClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GpsdData>(_response);
        Console.WriteLine(resultClass.ToString());

        Thread.Sleep(10);
    }

    client.Close();
}
```

[My Github](https://github.com/Ghosttje/GPSD-CSharp-Library/tree/development)

Comment: This will be your best friend : http://catb.org/gpsd/client-howto.html#_what_gpsd_does_and_what_it_cannot_do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out how I connect to the service: like `@x...` says it is all in the link: 
[link](http://catb.org/gpsd/client-howto.html#_what_gpsd_does_and_what_it_cannot_do)

The command I need to send is:

```
var byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("?WATCH={\"enable\":true,\"json\":true}");
                client.Client.Send(byteData);
```